# Redimensionar imagem em java

Tags: java, imagem

Estou com o seguinte problema. Tenho uma aplicação que pega uma imagem e carrega em um *buffer* e depois tenho que redimensionar ela. Porém, usando o método `getScaledInstance()` a imagem perde muita qualidade.

Abaixo o trecho que carregada a imagem e a redimensiona:

```
try {
    BufferedImage imagem = ImageIO.read(new File(
            "D:\\Temp\\Printer\\recibo2.jpg"));     
    Image imagemMenor = imagem.getScaledInstance(600, 835, page);
    g2d.drawImage(imagemMenor, 0, 0, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Peço que me indiquem caminhos para contornar esse problema.

Comment: Você pode postar um exemplo da imagem original e da imagem ampliada?

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz uma breve pesquisa de como redimensionar imagens em `Java`, e descobri que existe mais de uma maneira, e isso normalmente significa uma troca entre **desempenho e qualidade**.

No seu caso, parece faltar a definição de um algorítmo (*hint*) para processar a imagem. Não defini-lo significa **optar pelo algorítmo padrão**, e este, por sua vez, significa **rapidez**.

**A solução imediata seria apenas alterar o algorítmo:**

```
Image imagemMenor = imagem.getScaledInstance(600, 835, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

E é uma das soluções mais atraentes, se falarmos de qualidade. Mas é também uma das *mais lentas*.

Uma dica que eu encontrei em muitos lugares, é a de não utilizar o `getScaledInstace()`, apenas o `drawImage()`, reduzindo a imagem **no máximo até metade do tamanho original dela**, e repetindo o processo se necessário.

> Surpreendentemente, esse processo em *loop* de reduzir a imagem diversas vezes, chega a ser dez vezes mais rápido que os outros!

Eu coloquei algumas maneiras de redimensionar uma imagem num mesmo programa, para fins de teste. Ao lado de cada seleção, está o tempo que levou para processar a imagem:

[image: Redimensionamento Padrão]

A diferença entre três das opções ("Smooth", "Multiplos Passos" e "Padrão"):

[image: Amostras de cada processo de imagem]

O código inalterado para redimensionar imagens usando multiplos passos, junto com uma boa explicação de como funcionam as `classes`, está neste link: [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Segue abaixo o meu código de teste:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class RedimensionarImagem extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    BufferedImage img, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5;
    JRadioButton radio1, radio2, radio3, radio4, radio5;
    JPanel painelRadio, painel2;
    JLabel minhaImagem;
    long tempInicial1, tempInicial2, tempInicial3, tempInicial4;
    long tempFinal1, tempFinal2, tempFinal3, tempFinal4;

    public RedimensionarImagem() {

        super(new BorderLayout());


        try {
            // URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/uVKJljD.jpg");
            // URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/Y4ReYrD.jpg");
            URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/kGbo3Ox.jpg");
            img = ImageIO.read(url);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        int imgLargura = img.getWidth();
        int imgAltura = img.getHeight();

        int porcentagem = 25;
        int pTamanho = 100 / porcentagem;

        tempInicial2 = System.nanoTime();
        img2 = usandoDraw1Passo(img, imgLargura/pTamanho,
                                imgAltura/pTamanho);
        tempFinal2 = System.nanoTime();

        tempInicial3 = System.nanoTime();
        img3 = usandoDrawVarios(img, imgLargura/pTamanho,
                                imgAltura/pTamanho);
        tempFinal3 = System.nanoTime();

        tempInicial1 = System.nanoTime();
        img1 = usandoGetScaled(img, imgLargura/pTamanho,
                               imgAltura/pTamanho, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        tempFinal1 = System.nanoTime();

        tempInicial4 = System.nanoTime();
        img4 = usandoGetScaled(img, imgLargura/pTamanho,
                               imgAltura/pTamanho, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        tempFinal4 = System.nanoTime();

        painelRadio = new JPanel();
        painel2 = new JPanel();

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");

        double segundos1 = (double)(tempFinal1 - tempInicial1) / 1000000000.0;
        double segundos2 = (double)(tempFinal2 - tempInicial2) / 1000000000.0;
        double segundos3 = (double)(tempFinal3 - tempInicial3) / 1000000000.0;
        double segundos4 = (double)(tempFinal4 - tempInicial4) / 1000000000.0;


        radio2 = new JRadioButton("Red. Bilinear de 1 Passo (" +
                                  df.format(segundos2) + "s)");
        radio3 = new JRadioButton("Red. Bil. Multiplos Passos (" +
                                  df.format(segundos3) + "s)");
        radio1 = new JRadioButton("Reducao \"Padrao\" (" +
                                  df.format(segundos1) + "s)");
        radio4 = new JRadioButton("Reducao \"Padrao Smooth\" (" +
                                  df.format(segundos4) + "s)");

        ButtonGroup grupo = new ButtonGroup();

        grupo.add(radio1);
        grupo.add(radio2);
        grupo.add(radio3);
        grupo.add(radio4);

        radio1.addActionListener(this);
        radio2.addActionListener(this);
        radio3.addActionListener(this);
        radio4.addActionListener(this);

        painel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        painelRadio.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        painelRadio.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));        

        painelRadio.add(radio1);
        painelRadio.add(radio2);
        painelRadio.add(radio3);
        painelRadio.add(radio4);

        minhaImagem = new JLabel();
        minhaImagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img3));
        painel2.add(minhaImagem);

        add(painelRadio, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(painel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                criarInterface();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void criarInterface() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Redimensionar Imagem");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent painelConteudo = new RedimensionarImagem();
        painelConteudo.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(painelConteudo);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (radio1.isSelected()) {
         minhaImagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
        }
        if (radio2.isSelected()) {
         minhaImagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));
        }
        if (radio3.isSelected()) {
         minhaImagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img3));
        }
        if (radio4.isSelected()) {
         minhaImagem.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img4));
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage usandoGetScaled(BufferedImage img,
                         int larguraFinal, int alturaFinal, int modo) {

    Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(larguraFinal, alturaFinal, modo);
    int width = tmp.getWidth(null);
    int height = tmp.getHeight(null);

    BufferedImage novaImagem = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                                   BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = novaImagem.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    return novaImagem;

    }

    public BufferedImage usandoDraw1Passo(BufferedImage img,
                         int larguraFinal, int alturaFinal) {

        int largura = img.getWidth();
        int altura = img.getHeight();
        BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(largura, altura,
                                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, larguraFinal, alturaFinal, null);
        g2.dispose();

        return tmp;
    }

    public BufferedImage usandoDrawVarios(BufferedImage img,
                         int larguraFinal, int alturaFinal) {

        BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage)img;

        int largura, altura;

        largura = img.getWidth();
        altura = img.getHeight();

        do {
            if (largura > larguraFinal) {
                largura /= 2;
                if (largura < larguraFinal) {
                    largura = larguraFinal;
                }
            }

            if (altura > alturaFinal) {
                altura /= 2;
                if (altura < alturaFinal) {
                    altura = alturaFinal;
                }
            }

            BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(largura, altura,
                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g3 = tmp.createGraphics();
            g3.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g3.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, largura, altura, null);
            g3.dispose();

            ret = tmp;
        } while (largura != larguraFinal || altura != alturaFinal);

        return ret;
    }

}
```

Fontes:

- [Re-sizing an image without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7951324/1579771)
- [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)
- [Javadoc - Class Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)
- [Javadoc - Controlling Rendering Quality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html)
- [Javadoc - Class BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage%28int,%20int,%20int%29)
- [Imgur - Wallpaper Gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2sBQ.jpg)